# What is the app store views and app units mean from apple app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, analytics

I am new to apple app store and I have just published my first app on app store. Now I received the app analytics weekly summary from apple. In the summary, app store views and app units. From my understanding, app store views mean number of people who view your app page on the app store and the app units is the number of people downloading your app.

But why is that my report turn out to be app units has the higher number than the app store views? This simply doesn't make sense. So, what is the app store views and app units mean from apple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

App Units

> The number of first-time app purchases made on the App Store using iOS
>   8 or later. App updates, downloads from the same Apple ID onto other
>   devices, and redownloads to the same device are not counted. Family
>   Sharing downloads are included for free apps, but not for paid apps.

App Store Views

> The number of times your app’s App Store page has been viewed on a
>   device using iOS 8 or later. Although apps can be downloaded without
>   visiting the app’s App Store product page, such as directly from
>   search results, only App Store product page views are counted.

[Source](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/iTunes_Connect_App_Analytics_Guide_v1.pdf)

If you read the last sentence in the App Store Views it could be that you have many direct downloads.

Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

The above about App Unit is now incorrect (perhaps it was previously written as such). App Units, according to Apple, are first time App Downloads (not installs/opens and not purchases) from the app store page:

App Units

The number of first-time app downloads made on the App Store using iOS 8 or tvOS 9, or later. App updates, downloads from the same Apple ID onto other devices, and redownloads to the same device are not counted. Family Sharing downloads are included for free apps, but not for paid apps.

Metrics and Measures - https://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/en.lproj/static.html#itc7bea1545f

Comment: URL is not longer available.